# Putting a vertical line after the second column of these two tables?

Tags: tables

Consider:

```
 \documentclass{article}
    
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
    
    \begin{document}    
    \begin{table}[!htb]
    \noindent\begin{tblr}{
                          colspec = {*{4}{Q[c,$]}},
                           row{1} = {mode=text},
                         row{2-Y} = {belowsep+=2pt}
                         }
            \toprule
        Parameter & Sensitivity index & Parameter & Sensitivity index\\
            \midrule
        x     & +1.000 
                    & x  & -0.328  \\
       x & -0.788 
                    & x       & -0.344    \\
        x & +0.231 
                    & x       & -0.518      \\
        x & +0.124 
                    & x & -0.023      \\
        x       & -5.785 
                    & \xi & +0.364      \\
        x       & -0.731 
                    & x       & -0.004                    \\
        
            \bottomrule
        \end{tblr}
    \caption{x}
    \end{table}
and
\begin{table}[!htb]
\small
\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = {| Q[c,$] X[l] |
                                   Q[c,$] X[l] |},
                       row{1} = {mode=text},
                     row{2-Y} = {belowsep+=2pt},
cells = {font=\fontsize{10}{11}}
                     }  
    \toprule
Parameter & Description & Parameter & Description\\
    \midrule
x     & Influx rate of the population 
            & x  & Progression rate of  asymptomatic to symptomatic compartment  \\
x & Natural death rate 
            & x       & Self-recovery rate of asymptomatic individuals \\
x & Transmission rate of the asymptomatic compartment 
            & x       & Self-recovery rate of symptomatic individuals      \\
x & Transmission rate of the symptomatic compartment 
            & x & Treatment rate of symptomatic individuals      \\
x       & Vaccination proportion of newborns
            & x     & Immunity loss rate     \\
x       & Vaccination rate of susceptibles 
            & x       & Disease induced death rate                    \\

    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{Description of parameters}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

1. How can we insert a vertical line after the second column in first table in the MWE?
2. How can we make the second table look like the first table(same thickness of lines and removing the outer border lines) but inserting a vertical line after the second column?

EDIT:

For 2) I did:

```
\documentclass{article}
        
        \usepackage{tabularray}
        \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
        
        \begin{document}  


 \begin{table}[!htb]
    \small
    \noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = { Q[c,$] X[l] |
                                       Q[c,$] X[l] },
                           row{1} = {mode=text},
                         row{2-Y} = {belowsep+=2pt},
    cells = {font=\fontsize{10}{11}}
                         }  
        \toprule
    Parameter & Description & Parameter & Description\\
        \midrule
    x     & Influx rate of the population 
                & x  & Progression rate of  asymptomatic to symptomatic compartment  \\
    x & Natural death rate 
                & x       & Self-recovery rate of asymptomatic individuals \\
    x & Transmission rate of the asymptomatic compartment 
                & x       & Self-recovery rate of symptomatic individuals      \\
    x & Transmission rate of the symptomatic compartment 
                & x & Treatment rate of symptomatic individuals      \\
    x      & Vaccination proportion of newborns
                & x     & Immunity loss rate     \\
   x       & Vaccination rate of susceptibles 
                & x       & Disease induced death rate                    \\
    
        \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
    \caption{x}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

But is the top rule and bottom rule identical to the first table in MWE? To me, it looks "less" thicker than the first table in MWE but I maybe wrong?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple unrelated questions in a single post. It would be better to split them into two posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm only going to answer your first question, you should move additional questions to a new post)

You can use `vline{3}={solid}` to add a vertical line after the 2nd column. However this will make your otherwise nice table, look less professional.

Instead I suggest to split the second horizontal rule to indicate a division:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}    
\begin{table}[!htb]
\noindent\begin{tblr}{
                    colspec = {*{4}{Q[c,$]}},
                    vline{3}={solid},
                     row{1} = {mode=text},
                   row{2-Y} = {belowsep+=2pt}
                   }
      \toprule
  Parameter & Sensitivity index & Parameter & Sensitivity index\\
      \midrule
  x     & +1.000 
              & x  & -0.328  \\
 x & -0.788 
              & x       & -0.344    \\
  x & +0.231 
              & x       & -0.518      \\
  x & +0.124 
              & x & -0.023      \\
  x       & -5.785 
              & \xi & +0.364      \\
  x       & -0.731 
              & x       & -0.004                    \\
  
      \bottomrule
  \end{tblr}
\caption{x}
\end{table}

  \begin{table}[!htb]
  \noindent\begin{tblr}{
                        colspec = {*{4}{Q[c,$]}},
                         row{1} = {mode=text},
                       row{2-Y} = {belowsep+=2pt}
                       }
          \toprule
      Parameter & Sensitivity index & Parameter & Sensitivity index\\
         \cmidrule[r]{1-2} \cmidrule[l]{3-4}
      x     & +1.000 
                  & x  & -0.328  \\
     x & -0.788 
                  & x       & -0.344    \\
      x & +0.231 
                  & x       & -0.518      \\
      x & +0.124 
                  & x & -0.023      \\
      x       & -5.785 
                  & \xi & +0.364      \\
      x       & -0.731 
                  & x       & -0.004                    \\
      
          \bottomrule
      \end{tblr}
  \caption{x}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain this `colspec = {*{4}{Q[c,$]}}`?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 That's 4 times a centred column with math mode.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 You're welcome!

Comment: Another way is `cells={mode=dmath}`?

Comment: @minhthien_2016  No, the equivalent would be  `cells={mode=math}`.

Comment: If you'd like display math columns, that would be `colspec = {*{4}{Q[c,$$]}}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142676/discussion-between-minhthien-2016-and-samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz).

Answer (score 1):

With use of the `siunitx` library and grouped rows, just first table:

```
documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{vline{3} = solid,   % <---
             colspec = {*{2}{Q[c,mode=math]Q[c, si={table-format=-1.3}]}},
              row{1} = {guard, mode=text},
            row{2-Z} = {rowsep=0pt},
            row{even[4-Z]} = {abovesep=3pt},
             }
    \toprule
Parameter & Sensitivity index & Parameter & Sensitivity index\\
    \midrule
x   &  1.000    & x     & -0.328    \\
x   & -0.788    & x     & -0.344    \\
x   &  0.231    & x     & -0.518    \\
x   &  0.124    & x     & -0.023    \\
x   & -5.785    & \xi   &  0.364    \\
x   & -0.731    & x     & -0.004    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{Caption of the first table}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum (1):**
And second table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htb]
\small
\begin{tblr}{vline{3},
             colspec = {*{2}{Q[c,mode=math] X[cmd=\RaggedRight]}},
              colsep = 4pt,
             row{1}  = {mode=text},
            row{2-Z} = {font=\linespread{0.9}\relax},
             }
    \toprule
Parameter & Description & Parameter & Description\\
    \midrule
x   & Influx rate of the population
        & x & Progression rate of  asymptomatic to symptomatic compartment  \\
x   & Natural death rate
        & x & Self-recovery rate of asymptomatic individuals \\
x   & Transmission rate of the asymptomatic compartment
        & x & Self-recovery rate of symptomatic individuals      \\
x   & Transmission rate of the symptomatic compartment
        & x & Treatment rate of symptomatic individuals      \\
x   & Vaccination proportion of newborns
        & x & Immunity loss rate     \\
x   & Vaccination rate of susceptibles
        & x & Disease induced death rate                    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{Description of parameters}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum (2):**
Many people don't like vertical lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htb]
\small
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {*{2}{Q[c,mode=math] X[cmd=\RaggedRight]}},
              colsep = 4pt,
             row{1}  = {mode=text},
            row{2-Z} = {font=\linespread{0.9}\relax},
             }
    \toprule
Parameter & Description & Parameter & Description\\
    \cmidrule[r]{1-2}   \cmidrule[l]{3-4}
x   & Influx rate of the population
        & x & Progression rate of  asymptomatic to symptomatic compartment  \\
x   & Natural death rate
        & x & Self-recovery rate of asymptomatic individuals \\
x   & Transmission rate of the asymptomatic compartment
        & x & Self-recovery rate of symptomatic individuals      \\
x   & Transmission rate of the symptomatic compartment
        & x & Treatment rate of symptomatic individuals      \\
x   & Vaccination proportion of newborns
        & x & Immunity loss rate     \\
x   & Vaccination rate of susceptibles
        & x & Disease induced death rate                    \\

    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{Description of parameters}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Following Sam's solution; do you think it looks more professional with the central line after the second column or if we remove it? In the second table, we have the same question as the last question

Comment: I would not draw vertical lines at all, but this is very opinion based. Instead it I would replace `\midrue` with `\cmidrule[r]{1-2}   \cmidrule[l]{3-4}`. See second addendum to answer.

Comment: Thank you! Both answers are very good :)